# how do you clear the value in textInput box in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a actionButton called addbtn. When clicked this button, it will take the input from a textInput box and create additional textInput's.

When I click the addbtn, and the textInput boxes create, the values in the txtInput box needs to clear so that I can add more textInput boxes.

This is the code:

ui:

```
ibrary(shiny)

  shinyUI(

    # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
    fluidPage(    


      # Generate a row with a sidebar
      sidebarLayout(      


        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("capacity", "Current Capacity:", 
                      min=0, max=100, value=10),
          c(list(
            textInput("service", "Application Component Name", ""),
            actionButton("addbtn", "Add Component"))),
            #lapply(seq(10), function(i) uiOutput(paste0("ui", i)))

            br(),
            br(), 
            br(),
            br(),
            br(),
          actionButton("calcbtn", "Calculate Projection")




        ),



        # Create a spot for the barplot
        mainPanel(
          textInput("inputWork","Volume", width="200px"),
          textInput("inputGrowth","Growth Rate", width="100px"),
          lapply(seq(10), function(i) uiOutput(paste0("ui", i)))
          #tags$p("Web"),
          #verbatimTextOutput("input_type_text")

        )

      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) 
{
  observeEvent(input$addbtn, {
    n <- isolate(input$addbtn)
    if (n == 0) return()

    # create n-th pair of text input and output
    output[[paste0("ui", n)]] <- renderUI(
      list(textInput(paste0("textin", n), isolate(input$service)),
           textOutput(paste0("textout", n))))
    updateTextInput(input$service, "Application Component Name", value="")
  })
  }
```

with this code, I am getting these errors:

```
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Stack trace (innermost first):
    64: updateTextInput
    63: observeEventHandler [C:\shiny\bcl/server.R#11]
     1: shiny::runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Comment: @Batanichek, I've update the original post with the ui code. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your problem in `updateTextInput`

in help

> Arguments
>
> session    The session object passed to function given to shinyServer.
>
> inputId    The id of the input object.
>
> label  The label to set for the input object.
>
> value  The value to set for the input object.

so your need  server like :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$addbtn, {
    n <- isolate(input$addbtn)
    if (n == 0) return()

    # create n-th pair of text input and output
    output[[paste0("ui", n)]] <- renderUI(
      list(textInput(paste0("textin", n), isolate(input$service)),
           textOutput(paste0("textout", n))))
    updateTextInput(session,"service", "Application Component Name", value="")
  })
  })
```

If your dont want to change `label` of `textInput` you can drop it in update :
 `updateTextInput(session,"service", value="")`

Comment: I have some other questions. Can we have a chat?

Comment: let try, but i not master in shiny( and not today )